# Массив Task ошибочно выполняет код

Tags: c#

Экспериментирую с Тасками, но вот проблема. У меня цикл от 130 до 150, который проверяет порты на адресе, и я знаю, что 135 открыт, но когда я делаю это через таски, он почему-то пишет что он закрыт, хотя если делать это последовательно через цикл, то показывает, что он открыт, есть ли какие-то мысли на данный счет? ... Я не исключаю, что я криворукий и ошибочно где-то что-то написал, прошу понять и ... показать где ошибка. Спасибо!

```
private void KKnop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Task[] tasks = new Task[160];
            for (int i = 130; i < 150; i++)
            {
                int ls = i;
                tasks[ls] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        s.Connect("192.168.1.65", ls);
                        if (s.Connected.ToString() == "True")
                        {
                            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                            {
                                ping_label.Text += ls + " " + s.Connected.ToString() + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "\n";
                                Pbar.Value++;
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                            {
                                ping_label.Text += ls + " " + s.Connected.ToString() + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "\n"; ;
                                Pbar.Value++;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            ping_label.Text += ls + " " + s.Connected.ToString() + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "\n";
                            Pbar.Value++;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` замените на `Task.Run`. И вы не можете с одного сокета создать кучу подключений одновременно, я полагаю. То есть для каждого порта нужно открывать сокет отдельно.

```
private async void KKnop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int startPort = 130;
    int endPort = 150;
    int range = endPort - startPort;
    int count = 0;
    IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s =>
    {
        ping_label.Text += s + Environment.NewLine;
        count++;
        Pbar.Value = Pbar.Maximum * count / range;
    });
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = startPort; i <= endPort; i++)
    {
        int ls = i;
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                s.Connect("192.168.1.65", ls);
                if (s.Connected)
                {
                    progress.Report($"{ls} {s.Connected} {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                }
                else
                {
                    progress.Report($"{ls} {s.Connected} {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                progress.Report($"{ls} {ex.Message}");
            }
        });
    });
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    progress.Report($"Сканирование завершено");
}
```